# LibreOffice6.1 broken after upgrading to texlive2018 from a PPA. Can't downgrade to LO5.16 under 16.04

Tags: 16.04, package-management, libreoffice, texlive

I'm running ubuntu 16.04. LibreOffice 6.13 was installed from PPA and texlive2015 was installed ubuntu repository.
I decided to install texlive2018 from a PPA:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive-2018/ubuntu xenial main
```

But now libreoffice fails to startup:

```
$ soffice
 (soffice:3720): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large
 (soffice:3720): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large
Application Error
```

To fix the issue, I tried several things:

1. removing .confid/libreoffice : **failed**
2. remove and purge texlive2018 : **failed**
3. remove texlive2018 PPA and try to reinstall texlive2015: **installing texlive2015 would erase quite everything previously installed (cuda for ex !!)**
4. remove texlive2018 PPA, remove libreoffice PPA to install LO5.16: it's impossible to install (see bellow), grossly that yields :

> E: Unable to fix problems, defective packages are in "keep as is"
>   mode.

```
$ sudo apt install libreoffice
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Certains paquets ne peuvent être installés. Ceci peut signifier
que vous avez demandé l'impossible, ou bien, si vous utilisez
la distribution unstable, que certains paquets n'ont pas encore
été créés ou ne sont pas sortis d'Incoming.
L'information suivante devrait vous aider à résoudre la situation : 

Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 libreoffice : Dépend: libreoffice-base mais ne sera pas installé

               Dépend: libreoffice-calc mais ne sera pas installé
               Dépend: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial4) mais ne sera pas installé
               Dépend: libreoffice-draw mais ne sera pas installé
               Dépend: libreoffice-impress mais ne sera pas installé
               Dépend: libreoffice-math mais ne sera pas installé
               Dépend: libreoffice-report-builder-bin mais ne sera pas installé
               Dépend: libreoffice-writer mais ne sera pas installé
               Dépend: libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer mais ne sera pas installé
               Dépend: python3-uno (>= 4.4.0~beta2) mais ne sera pas installé
               Recommande: libreoffice-gnome mais ne sera pas installé ou
                           libreoffice-kde mais ne sera pas installé
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».
```

Texlive is functionnal, it can compile a tex document. I Have no more idea to get a healty state (texlive2018+libreoffice6.13 or texlive2015+LO6.13).

The repo are:

```
~$ cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ && cat *.list
deb file:///var/cuda-repo-9-2-local /
deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64 /
deb [arch=i386,amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://www.geogebra.net/linux/ stable main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive-2018/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive-2018/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
deb file:///var/nccl-repo-2.2.13-ga-cuda9.2 /
deb file:///var/nv-tensorrt-repo-cuda9.2-ga-trt4.0.1.6-20180612 /
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu xenial main
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command succeeded to unlock the situation:

```
$ sudo apt full-upgrade
[sudo] Mot de passe de jeanpat : 
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Calcul de la mise à jour... Fait
Les NOUVEAUX paquets suivants seront installés :
  libpoppler73 libquazip5-1
Les paquets suivants ont été conservés :
  cuda cuda-drivers
Les paquets suivants seront mis à jour :
  fonts-sil-padauk fonts-texgyre libharfbuzz-icu0 libpixman-1-0 libpoppler-glib8 libpoppler-qt5-1 poppler-utils tex-common tex-gyre texstudio texstudio-doc texstudio-l10n
12 mis à jour, 2 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 2 non mis à jour.
Il est nécessaire de prendre 24,8 Mo dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 8 387 ko d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n] O
Réception de:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive-2018/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 tex-common all 6.09~16.04.york0 [53,4 kB]
Réception de:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive-2018/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 fonts-sil-padauk all 3.003-1~16.04.york0 [1 327 kB]
Réception de:3 http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 libquazip5-1 amd64 0.7.1-1 [70,0 kB]
Réception de:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive-2018/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 fonts-texgyre all 20160520-1~16.04.york0 [8 769 kB]
Réception de:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive-2018/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libharfbuzz-icu0 amd64 1.7.2-1~16.04.york0 [9 612 B]                                                                   
Réception de:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive-2018/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libpixman-1-0 amd64 0.34.0-1~ubuntu16.04.1york0 [235 kB]                                                               
Réception de:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive-2018/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libpoppler73 amd64 0.62.0-2ubuntu3~16.04.york0 [809 kB]                                                                
Réception de:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive-2018/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libpoppler-glib8 amd64 0.62.0-2ubuntu3~16.04.york0 [126 kB]                                                            
Réception de:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive-2018/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libpoppler-qt5-1 amd64 0.62.0-2ubuntu3~16.04.york0 [159 kB]                                                            
Réception de:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive-2018/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 poppler-utils amd64 0.62.0-2ubuntu3~16.04.york0 [171 kB]                                                              
Réception de:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive-2018/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 tex-gyre all 20160520-1~16.04.york0 [5 043 kB]                                                                        
Réception de:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive-2018/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 texstudio-doc all 2.12.6+debian-1~16.04.york0 [2 141 kB]                                                              
Réception de:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive-2018/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 texstudio-l10n all 2.12.6+debian-1~16.04.york0 [555 kB]                                                               
Réception de:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive-2018/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 texstudio amd64 2.12.6+debian-1~16.04.york0 [5 305 kB]                                                                
24,8 Mo réceptionnés en 24s (997 ko/s)                                                                                                                                                                         
(Lecture de la base de données... 341032 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../tex-common_6.09~16.04.york0_all.deb ...
Dépaquetage de tex-common (6.09~16.04.york0) sur (6.04ubuntu1) ...
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../fonts-sil-padauk_3.003-1~16.04.york0_all.deb ...
Dépaquetage de fonts-sil-padauk (3.003-1~16.04.york0) sur (2.80-2) ...
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../fonts-texgyre_20160520-1~16.04.york0_all.deb ...
Dépaquetage de fonts-texgyre (20160520-1~16.04.york0) sur (20150923-1) ...
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../libharfbuzz-icu0_1.7.2-1~16.04.york0_amd64.deb ...
Dépaquetage de libharfbuzz-icu0:amd64 (1.7.2-1~16.04.york0) sur (1.0.1-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../libpixman-1-0_0.34.0-1~ubuntu16.04.1york0_amd64.deb ...
Dépaquetage de libpixman-1-0:amd64 (0.34.0-1~ubuntu16.04.1york0) sur (0.33.6-1) ...
Sélection du paquet libpoppler73:amd64 précédemment désélectionné.
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../libpoppler73_0.62.0-2ubuntu3~16.04.york0_amd64.deb ...
Dépaquetage de libpoppler73:amd64 (0.62.0-2ubuntu3~16.04.york0) ...
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../libpoppler-glib8_0.62.0-2ubuntu3~16.04.york0_amd64.deb ...
Dépaquetage de libpoppler-glib8:amd64 (0.62.0-2ubuntu3~16.04.york0) sur (0.41.0-0ubuntu1.8) ...
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../libpoppler-qt5-1_0.62.0-2ubuntu3~16.04.york0_amd64.deb ...
Dépaquetage de libpoppler-qt5-1:amd64 (0.62.0-2ubuntu3~16.04.york0) sur (0.41.0-0ubuntu1.8) ...
Sélection du paquet libquazip5-1:amd64 précédemment désélectionné.
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../libquazip5-1_0.7.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Dépaquetage de libquazip5-1:amd64 (0.7.1-1) ...
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../poppler-utils_0.62.0-2ubuntu3~16.04.york0_amd64.deb ...
Dépaquetage de poppler-utils (0.62.0-2ubuntu3~16.04.york0) sur (0.41.0-0ubuntu1.8) ...
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../tex-gyre_20160520-1~16.04.york0_all.deb ...
Dépaquetage de tex-gyre (20160520-1~16.04.york0) sur (20150923-1) ...
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../texstudio-doc_2.12.6+debian-1~16.04.york0_all.deb ...
Dépaquetage de texstudio-doc (2.12.6+debian-1~16.04.york0) sur (2.10.8+debian-1) ...
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../texstudio-l10n_2.12.6+debian-1~16.04.york0_all.deb ...
Dépaquetage de texstudio-l10n (2.12.6+debian-1~16.04.york0) sur (2.10.8+debian-1) ...
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../texstudio_2.12.6+debian-1~16.04.york0_amd64.deb ...
Dépaquetage de texstudio (2.12.6+debian-1~16.04.york0) sur (2.10.8+debian-1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour doc-base (0.10.7) ...
Traitement de 2 fichiers de documentation supprimés, 2 fichiers de documentation modifiés, 1 fichier de documentation ajouté…
Enregistrement des documents avec scrollkeeper…
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour fontconfig (2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.2) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20180209-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Paramétrage de tex-common (6.09~16.04.york0) ...
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... done.
Running mktexlsr /var/lib/texmf ... done.
Building format(s) --all.
    This may take some time... done.
Paramétrage de fonts-sil-padauk (3.003-1~16.04.york0) ...
Paramétrage de fonts-texgyre (20160520-1~16.04.york0) ...
Paramétrage de libharfbuzz-icu0:amd64 (1.7.2-1~16.04.york0) ...
Paramétrage de libpixman-1-0:amd64 (0.34.0-1~ubuntu16.04.1york0) ...
Paramétrage de libpoppler73:amd64 (0.62.0-2ubuntu3~16.04.york0) ...
Paramétrage de libpoppler-glib8:amd64 (0.62.0-2ubuntu3~16.04.york0) ...
Paramétrage de libpoppler-qt5-1:amd64 (0.62.0-2ubuntu3~16.04.york0) ...
Paramétrage de libquazip5-1:amd64 (0.7.1-1) ...
Paramétrage de poppler-utils (0.62.0-2ubuntu3~16.04.york0) ...
Paramétrage de tex-gyre (20160520-1~16.04.york0) ...
Paramétrage de texstudio-doc (2.12.6+debian-1~16.04.york0) ...
Paramétrage de texstudio (2.12.6+debian-1~16.04.york0) ...
Paramétrage de texstudio-l10n (2.12.6+debian-1~16.04.york0) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour tex-common (6.09~16.04.york0) ...
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... done.
Running mktexlsr /var/lib/texmf ... done.
```

The icons are still to great but libreoffice starts:

```
~$ soffice

(soffice:5890): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large

(soffice:5890): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large

(soffice:5890): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large

(soffice:5890): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large
```